# Error Calling DB2 Stored Procedure

Tags: db2-400

I defined a stored procedure with input and output parameters and am getting the following error when I try to call the stored procedure.

[SQL0312] Variable KUNNR not defined or not usable.

## Here is the call:

CALL R3QA6DATA.SP_ADDRESS_CHANGES ('1999-12-31 23:59:59', '2016-06-01 23:59:59', :KUNNR,:KUNN2,:NAME1,:NAME2,:STRAS,:ORT01,:REGIO,:PSTLZ,:LAND1,:TELF1,:TELFX,:DEFPA)
GO

## Here is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE R3QA6DATA.SP_ADDRESS_CHANGES 
(IN STARTDATE TIMESTAMP, IN ENDDATE TIMESTAMP, 
 OUT KUNNR GRAPHIC(10), OUT KUNN2 GRAPHIC(10), OUT NAME1 GRAPHIC(35), OUT NAME2 GRAPHIC(35), OUT STRAS GRAPHIC(35), OUT ORT01 GRAPHIC(35),
 OUT REGIO GRAPHIC(3), OUT PSTLZ GRAPHIC(10), OUT LAND1 GRAPHIC(3), OUT TELF1 GRAPHIC(16), OUT TELFX GRAPHIC(31), OUT DEFPA GRAPHIC(1) )

LANGUAGE SQL

BEGIN 
    SELECT DISTINCT 
         knvp.kunnr 
        , knvp.kunn2 
        , kna1.name1 
        , kna1.name2 
        , kna1.stras 
        , kna1.ort01 
        , kna1.regio 
        , kna1.pstlz  
        , kna1.land1 
        , kna1.telf1 
        , kna1.telfx 
        , knvp.defpa 
        INTO KUNNR, KUNN2, NAME1, NAME2, STRAS, ORT01, REGIO, PSTLZ, LAND1, TELF1, TELFX, DEFPA
    FROM 
        R3QA6DATA.KNA1 AS kna1 
        INNER JOIN  
        R3QA6DATA.ZMBCM AS zmbcm 
        ON  
        kna1.KUNNR = zmbcm.KUNAG 
        INNER JOIN 
        R3QA6DATA.KNVV AS knvv 
        ON 
        ( kna1.KUNNR = knvv.KUNNR ) 
        INNER JOIN 
        R3QA6DATA.KNVP AS knvp  
        ON 
        (  
            knvv.KUNNR = knvp.KUNNR  
            AND 
            knvv.VKORG = knvp.VKORG 
            AND 
            knvv.VTWEG = knvp.VTWEG 
            AND 
            knvv.SPART = knvp.SPART 
        ) 
    WHERE 
        kna1.MANDT = '010' 
        AND 
        knvp.PARVW IN ('WE', 'AG') 
        AND 
        ( 
            knvv.VKORG = zmbcm.VKORG 
            AND 
            knvv.VTWEG = zmbcm.VTWEG 
            AND 
            knvv.SPART = zmbcm.SPART 
        ) 
        AND 
        kna1.loevm = ' ' 
        AND 
        knvv.loevm = ' ' 
        AND 
        knvp.KUNN2 IN 
        ( 
            SELECT  
                SUBSTRING(bdcp2.tabkey, 4, 10) 
            FROM 
                R3QA6DATA.BDCP2 AS bdcp2 
            WHERE 
                bdcp2.mestype = 'DEBMAS' 
                AND 
                ( 
                    (  bdcp2.tabname = 'KNA1' 
                    AND 
                    bdcp2.fldname IN  
                    ('NAME1' 
                    , 'NAME2' 
                    , 'STRAS' 
                    , 'ORT01' 
                    , 'REGIO' 
                    , 'LAND1' 
                    , 'PSTLZ' 
                    , 'TELF1' 
                    , 'TELFX') ) 
                    OR 
                    (  bdcp2.tabname = 'KNVP' ) 
                ) 
                AND 
                (  
                    bdcp2.cretime > STARTDATE 
                    AND  
                    bdcp2.cretime < ENDDATE
                ) 
        ) 
        AND 
        zmbcm.STOREID = 4 ;
END 
Go
```

Comment: Where are you calling it from?  KUNNR apparently isn't a valid variable at the point of the call.

Comment: I am calling it from Aqua Data Studio ....                                                      CALL R3QA6DATA.SP_ADDRESS_CHANGES ('1999-12-31 23:59:59', '2016-06-01 23:59:59', :KUNNR,:KUNN2,:NAME1,:NAME2,:STRAS,:ORT01,:REGIO,:PSTLZ,:LAND1,:TELF1,:TELFX,:DEFPA)
GO

Comment: Seems unlikely that Aqua uses the `:KUNNR` format for variables.  But I''m  not familiar with the product.  You should probably add a tag for that product to your question.

Answer (score 0):

In RPGLE or COBOL this issue usually happens if you have the variables defined in an external source and accessed through COPY statement. If this is the case in your problem then try using the source through INCLUDE.